# javascript delegate style to element

Tags: javascript, delegation

I've maded this in jquery that works fine:

```
$(document).delegate('i', 'click', function(_this){
    console.log(_this.target);
    this.parentElement.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.style.position = "fixed";
    this.parentElement.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.style.left = '5px';
    this.parentElement.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.style.top = '50px';
    this.parentElement.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.style.width = "200px";
    this.parentElement.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.style.height = "125px";
});
```

but I need to make it in pure javascript, NO jquery.

```
document.addEventListener("click",function(e) {
 if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == "I") {   
    console.log(e.target);
    this.parentElement.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.style.position = "fixed";
    this.parentElement.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.style.left = '5px';
    this.parentElement.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.style.top = '50px';
    this.parentElement.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.style.width = "200px";
    this.parentElement.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.style.height = "125px";
 }
});
```

This does not work... what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: it's `tagName`, not `nodeName`

Comment: now I've tried with tagName, but with no success..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through all i's and bind the event on the element.

```
 Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("i"), function (elem) {
     elem.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
         this.parentElement.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.style.position = "fixed";
         this.parentElement.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.style.left = '5px';
         this.parentElement.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.style.top = '50px';
         this.parentElement.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.style.width = "200px";
         this.parentElement.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.style.height = "125px";
     });
 })
```

Delegate version:

```
 document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        if (e.target && e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == "i") {
            e.target.parentElement.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.style.position = "fixed";
            e.target.parentElement.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.style.left = '5px';
            e.target.parentElement.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.style.top = '50px';
            e.target.parentElement.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.style.width = "200px";
            e.target.parentElement.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.style.height = "125px";
        }
    });
```

Comment: It's `elem`, not `i`, and this isn't delegated!

Comment: @hatsjoem: TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined

Comment: Updated. should be elem and not i, like @adeneo mentioned

Comment: And it's still not delegated.

Comment: Updated, it has the delegated version too.

Comment: Note that it still should be `tagName`

Comment: Changed it too tagName

Comment: Why should it be tagName? I've read some comments and most of them says nodeName should be used, but it isn't support in IE 5 and IE 5.5